# How do I make my submit button have white text with a red background?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make my submit button have a red background and white text. I am using css style within the html `<head>` section. I have tried this:

```
input [type="Submit"] {
   color: white; 
   background: red;
}
```

But this does not work. Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going on?

```
https://dash.generalassemb.ly/projects/build-your-own-personal-website
```

Comment: What's this link?

Comment: Hmm if you have button then why you are styling `input`? Can you provide html markup for this button? Maybe you mean `button[type="submit"]` (note `submit` in lowercase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS syntax is wrong: don't put a space between `input` and `[type="Submit"]`.
Here is your code:

```css
input[type="Submit"] {
   color: white; 
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: @DanO'Neil No problem :)